# AJAX variable not defined but it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an AJAX call to a JSON page that grab variables to populate a playlist for an HTML5 music player. I'm trying to have it so the playlist data updates every minute since its grabbing the information from a radio. I also dont want it to refresh the player itself, only the playlist. Everything works great except I'm getting `myPlaylist is not defined` I'm also trying to come up with the best way to refresh the AJAX call every minute... but one thing at a time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function ajax_playlist(str1, callback){     
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data, status, xhr){  
                    callback(data);
                    console.log(arguments);
                }
            });
        }

        ajax_playlist("str", function(pl) {
             myPlaylist = [
                {
                    mp3:'http://radio.gnradio.org:9966/vod/mp4:audio/file.m4a/playlist.m3u8',
                    artist:pl.data[0].track.artist,
                    title:pl.data[0].track.title,
                    cover:pl.data[0].track.imageurl
                }
            ];
         });


        var description = 'Welcome to SilvertoneRadio.com BETA Online player. We will be gradually improving it.';

        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `function ajax_playlist(str1, callback){  ...` shouldn't be in the `ready`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myPlaylist` is defined when the anonymous function passed to `ajax_playlist` is called.

That function is passed as the argument named `callback`.

That is called in the success function passed to the `ajax` method.

Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is asynchronous.

The success function won't be called until the HTTP response is received and processed.

So what happens is:

1. Ajax HTTP request is sent
2. `description` has a value assigned to it
3. `ttwMusicPlayer` is called (with `myPlaylist` which is currently `undefined`)
4. HTTP response is received
5. `myPlaylist` gets a value assigned to it

Move all the code that depends on `myPlaylist` having a value into your callback function.

Comment: This works, but wouldn't this refresh the entire player when I implement the refresh?

Comment: Wrap the "Load the player" code with an `if` statement that checks to see if it has already been loaded … and note that overwriting a global variable with a new value won't overwrite the original array that you have already passed to the player function.

Comment: Would it be asking too much if you could provide an example of the if statement?

Comment: The easiest approach would probably be to look for the DOM modifications made by loading the player. Since I have no idea what those are, I can't write an example. Use your DOM inspector to figure out what you need to look for.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is *asynchronous*, anything that depends on its result MUST be called in the success callback!

Move the `ttwMusicPlayer` call inside the `function(pl) { ... }` block (after the `myPlaylist = [...];`)

Comment: Wouldn't that refresh the entire player?

Comment: Um... no? Because you won't be loading the player until the playlist has loaded, right?